# Elasticsearch Ingest Node versus Logstash, etc

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a general question about Elasticsearch strategy.  We're just starting out and we have a stack of unstructured logs (30-40 logs, ~300GB data/week).  I had some questions about how to best approach bringing this data into Elasticsearch.

- Ingest Node vs Logstash
- Logstash Plugins: Grok vs Dissect

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did not use ingest node directly in production but I think, [this article](https://sematext.com/blog/2016/04/25/elasticsearch-ingest-node-vs-logstash-performance/) is really helpful about.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of information I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I use filebeat sending data directly to elastic ingest node. Logstash is not necessary any more.

And grok is my favourite.